# How to use a second docker instance?

Tags: docker, postgrest

Assuming that the command for a second docker instance is

```
docker run --rm --net=host -p 3002:3002 -e SERVER_PORT="3002" \
 -e PGRST_DB_URI="postgres://postgres@localhost/prod2"    \
 -e PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE="postgres" postgrest/postgrest
```

it results

```
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
Attempting to connect to the database...
Listening on port 3000
postgrest: Network.Socket.bind: resource busy (Address already in use)
```

That makes no sense because using `-p 3002:3002 -e SERVER_PORT="3002"`... Is it possible to run? Where is the configuration error?

NOTE: the first docker was implemented by `docker run -d --net=host -p 3000:3000 -e PGRST_DB_URI="postgres://postgres@localhost/prod0" -e PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE="postgres" postgrest/postgrest`

---

See also https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just misspelled the server port environment variable name, you're missing `PGRST` from the beginning in the second command.

Use `-e PGRST_SERVER_PORT=3002` instead of `-e SERVER_PORT`.

You get a warning because `-p` is ignored when using network host, but that does not seem to be an issue. Anyway, you can remove the `-p` settings from the commands and use just `--net=host`.